# error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I am using Angular 2 with TypeScript 2.

When I use

```
let labels: string[] | number[] = [];
// let labels: Array<number> | Array<string> = [];

labels.push(1);
```

it gives me error:

> error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call
>   signature.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Changing

```
let labels: string[] | number[] = [];
```

to either of these

```
let labels: (string | number)[] = [];
let labels: Array<number|string> = [];
```

will solve the issue.

Comment: I realize this is old, but figured I'd ask here anyway... I don't think `string[] | number[]` is equivalent to `(string | number)[]`. I think the first option means `labels` will be either an array of _all_ strings, or an array of _all_ numbers. While the second option means `labels` is an array whose contents can be strings or numbers, interchangeably. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @austinbruch Yes, you're right. Here is more info: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10620. In that link, the same issue is happening to his code using `filter` because I imagine `filter` uses `push` under the covers. It makes sense that `push` doesn't work because: if `labels` is `string[]` rather than `number[]` than this code obviously wouldn't work: `labels.push(1)`.